# How to disable input readonly in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I've a problem in my Laravel project. In a form I've the input with readonly attribute

```
<input type="text" name="anamFam" id="anamFam" value="{{$aFam->anam_cont}}" readonly>
```

and when I press the button edit I need to disable or remove the readonly attribute. So I try to use javascript in this way

```
function edit() {
    document.getElementById('anamFam').readOnly=false; 
}
```

Or using this in js:

```
document.getElementById('anamFamiliare').removeAttribute('readonly')
```

And in jQuery I tried in this way

```
$(document).ready(function ( e) {
        $(document).on("click", "#edit", function (e) {
            $(':input').removeAttr('readonly')
        })
    })
```

Or using this in jQuery:

```
$(':input').prop('readonly',false)
```

So when I click the button something happens as the input border become black, but when I try to edit in the input I can't edit as the pointer doesn't appear. So what is the problem

**EDIT**

I solved using `disabled` attribute

Comment: first (native) js version works as expected: https://jsbin.com/wuqikukiki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: can you check in console (in google chrome) if there is any error?

Comment: using disabled and readonly is two different things. you might run into issues with disabled attribute

Comment: Hi simone! instead of writing the solution as an edit to the question, write it as an answer instead and mark it as accepted. That way it'll be easier to help others and you'd be rewarded for that (I'd definitely give you an upvote now).

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery code, use the following line instead of what you are using

```
$("#anamFam").attr("readonly", false);
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

for your scenario, it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#edit').click(function(){
   $("#anamFam").attr("readonly", false); 

   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('awake_morning_{{$el->id}}').readOnly=false"
```

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing an answer. Please take a bit of time to explain your answer, it can help the OP and future readers.